# Why My Collection View Doesn't show my camera roll?

Tags: swift3, collectionview, camera-roll

I have a collection view that should shows camera roll photos But It didn't show any thing! 
I saw similar questions But Their code didn't work !
I added privacy for using album photos in Info.plist 
here is my code

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    grabPhotos()
}
func grabPhotos() {

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true

    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

      if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions) {



        if fetchResult.count > 0 {


            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {

                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {


                    image , error in



                    imageArray.append(image!)

                })




            }







        }
        else {

            print("No Photos")
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        }



    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count


    }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


            let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView


             imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]


             return cell


    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
    UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1




    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)


}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0 
}
}
```

**It Shows Nothing I read Similar questions But they didn't help me**

Comment: did you try to reload collectionview after fetching images?

Comment: BTW it is good to call `super.viewDidLoad()` before `grabPhotos()`